# Initialise weights in tensorflow sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Is there any way by which we can initialise weights (w vector) in our sequential model tensorflow?
I am using the code shown below fr my neural network and want to initialise the weights my myself

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense 
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1],activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1]/2,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1]/2,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1]/2,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(x=X_train,y=y_train,epochs=200,validation_data=(X_val,y_val))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this

```
for layer in model.layers:
    init_layer_weight = [] # the weights yourself in this layer
    layer.set_weights(init_layer_weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.
Check the documentation on this link: https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers/
They show you how you can use some of their initializers(TruncatedNormal, RandomUniform, GlorotUniform..),and  at the bottom of the page they give you an example for a custom initializer setup, like this one:

```
def my_init(shape, dtype=None):
    return tf.random.normal(shape, dtype=dtype)
layer = Dense(64, kernel_initializer=my_init)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to provide `Input()` layer, like in code below. This allows layers to actually compute their kernels/weights sizes. Also use '//2' instead of '/2' in your code for integer division.

After that you may access layers from `model.layers` list, this list includes all layers except input layer. On each layer you can call '.set_weights(...)', this method accepts python list of two elements - first element is kernel weights, second is bias weights, both weights should be numpy arrays. For `Dense` layer type kernel is 2D array with number of rows equal to input size (previous dense output nodes count) and number of columns equal to number of this dense layer nodes/outputs. Bias is 1D array of size equal to number of this dense layer nodes/outputs.

You may also read about [.set_weights(...)](https://keras.io/api/layers/base_layer/).

In the next code for example I set weights for Layer 2 & 3.

```
import tensorflow as tf, numpy as np, tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense 
X_train = np.array([[1.,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
model=Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Input(X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1],activation='relu')) # Layer 0
model.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1]//2,activation='relu')) # Layer 1
model.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1]//2,activation='relu')) # Layer 2
model.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1]//2,activation='relu')) # Layer 3
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')) # Layer 4
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='binary_crossentropy')
#model.fit(x=X_train,y=y_train,epochs=200,validation_data=(X_val,y_val))

# Set weights e.g. for Layers 2, 3
for layer in model.layers[2:4]:
    print('Weights before', layer.get_weights())
    layer.set_weights([
        np.array([
            [1., 2],
            [3 , 4],
        ]),
        np.array([
            5., 6,
        ]),
    ])
    print('Weights after', layer.get_weights())
```